# Add a TensorFlow Dataset with Tensors of unknown size

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to add a TensorFlow dataset to TFDS which contains a bunch of rank 2 tensors with unknown shapes. To define the features I use the following feature `tfds.features.Tensor(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.float32)`. However, when I try to load the dataset it fails with the error:

```
NotImplementedError: Specification error for feature k (TensorInfo(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.float32)): Tensor with a unknown dimension not at the first position not supported: TensorInfo(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.float32)
```

A minimal example to reproduce the error ([Real example on Github](https://github.com/HedgehogCode/tensorflow-datasets-bw/blob/master/tensorflow_datasets_bw/schelten_kernels.py)):

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds


class RandomTensors(tfds.core.GeneratorBasedBuilder):

    VERSION = tfds.core.Version('0.1.0')

    def _info(self):
        return tfds.core.DatasetInfo(
            builder=self,
            description="",
            features=tfds.features.FeaturesDict({
                'k':
                tfds.features.Tensor(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.float32)
            }),
            homepage="",
            citation="",
        )

    def _split_generators(self, dl_manager: tfds.download.DownloadManager):
        return [
            tfds.core.SplitGenerator(
                name=tfds.Split.TEST,
                gen_kwargs={},
            ),
        ]

    def _generate_examples(self):
        for idx in range(100):
            size = np.random.uniform(10, 20, size=(2, )).astype(np.int32)
            k = np.random.normal(size=size).astype(np.float32)
            yield idx, {'k': k}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = tfds.load('random_tensors', split='test')
```

Are tensors with unknown dimensions not supported in TensorFlow Datasets? Or do I have an an error in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible to do with TensorFlow Datasets, because, as the error message explains, only the first dimension (typically the batch dimension) can be dynamic.

Related to this, the `tf.data.Dataset` object typically expects a rectangular array. The following fails, for example:

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[1], [1, 2]])
```

This would be possible to do directly with a `tf.data.Dataset` object, but you would not be able to batch the samples in a batch size >= 2 because their shapes are different.

```py
def _generate_examples():
    for idx in range(100):
        size = np.random.uniform(10, 20, size=(2, )).astype(np.int32)
        k = np.random.normal(size=size).astype(np.float32)
        yield k

d = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(_generate_examples, output_types=np.float32)
next(iter(d))  # Works!

next(iter(d.batch(2)))
# Fails with error: 
# InvalidArgumentError: Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0.
# First element had shape [11,10] and element 1 had shape [13,17].
```

---

You might want to explore the possibility of using a larger tensor with a static shape, and then filling that with a dynamically sized smaller tensor. That way you have a static shape, but still have dynamically shaped data. The shape of the dynamic data can be a feature of the dataset, which is yielded in the generator along with the index and data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will consider your suggestion.
Can you explain why it works with images with both first dimensions being dynamic (default for `tfds.features.Image()`)?
Also a `tf.data.Dataset` can be created from these Tensors of dynamic size by using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`.